# Update Form button in InfoPath

Tags: c#, infopath

I have an InfoPath that is being deployed as a web-form to SharePoint, and it contains much C# back-end code.  Most of the form works fine, but I had to insert an "update form" button so that any back-end code can run.  Is there another way of calling this code/button when InfoPath controls change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each control have ability to force post back on change: properties of control -> browser forms -> Always.